# Swift safely unwrapping optinal strings and ints

Tags: swift, swifty-json, forced-unwrapping

When I am about to fire my segue for the 2nd view I also send some values like this:

```
if let aTime = ads[indexPath.row]["unix_t"].int {
    toView.time = aTime
}

if let aTitle = ads[indexPath.row]["title"].string {
    toView.title = aTitle
}
```

In the second VC I have declared the varibles like:

```
var time: Int?
var title: String?
```

and this is how I unwrap the values:

```
if time != nil {
   timeLabel.text = String(time!)
}

if title != nil {
   titleLabel.text = title!
}
```

This all works I never get any error caused by unwrapped varibles or nil values. But is there any easier way to do it?

Right now it feels like I am checking too much

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I can think of three alternatives.

1. `if/let`. Very similar to your current option, but you don't have to implicitly unwrap.

   ```
   if let time = time {
       timeLabel.text = "\(time)"
   }

   if let title = title {
       titleLabel.text = title
   }
   ```

   You can even unwrap them on the same line. The downside to this is that if one of them is `nil`, then neither label will be set.

   ```
   if let time = time, let title = title {
       timeLabel.text = "\(time)"
       titleLabel.text = title
   }
   ```
2. `guard/let`. If these are in a function like `setupViews()`, then you can one-line your unwrapping like so:

   ```
   func setupViews() {
       guard let time = time, let title = title else { return }
       timeLabel.text = "\(time)"
       titleLabel.text = title
   }
   ```
3. You can use default values and the `??` operator to unwrap quickly.

   ```
   timeLabel.text = "\(time ?? 0)"
   titleLabel.text = title ?? ""
   ```

Comment: For a 4th and 5th alternative, see vadian's answer and Martin R's comment to the question.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `Nil Coalescing Operator` too as given in the [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html):

> The nil coalescing operator (a ?? b) unwraps an optional a if it contains a value, or returns a default value b if a is nil. The expression a is always of an optional type. The expression b must match the type that is stored inside a.
>
> The nil coalescing operator is shorthand for the code below:
>
> `a != nil ? a! : b`

Answer (score 2):

```
if let time = time {
    timeLabel.text = "\(time)"
}

if let title = title {
    titleLabel.text = title
}
```

It's the same as with your JSON

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are checking too much (twice).

Since only non-optional values are passed you can declare the variables non-optional

```
var time = 0
var title = ""
```

and set the labels

```
timeLabel.text = "\(time)"
titleLabel.text = title
```

The strong type system of Swift highly recommends first to consider

> *Can I accomplish this without optionals?*

and – if there is no other option – then use optionals.

Comment: You mean giving them "dummy" values in the second VC? So that it will fallback to the dummy values in case no value was never passed in the segue

Comment: @user2636197 You have to decide how to handle errors. If not-passing a value is valid, then use an optional. If not passing a value should be considered an error, then you can just use forced-unwrapping without checking.

Comment: If this solution suits your design, yes

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to check nil condition in the first view. 
Please follow below code:

`toView.time = ads[indexPath.row]["unix_t"] as? Int`

`toView.title = ads[indexPath.row]["title"] as? String`

time and title variable in second view are optionals. So, when you assign a value to toView.time and toView.title, it will either assign the value of type time and title respectively or nil.